# ROBLOX: How to trigger a change text?

Tags: lua, roblox

I need some help on how I can make a simple script where a player touches a invisible part (trigger) then the text gui changes. I know how to change the text with the script.Parent.Text = "Somethingandso" But I dont know how to link that to a trigger. Any help?

Comment: Hey, try adding more information consisting of what you tried in your future questions, I don't want to downvote your question since you are new, but this is a site where you would 99% of the time get downvotes and no answers for not showing your effort!

Answer (score 0):

Touched is the event you are looking for
In RBX.Lua you connect events using the **:connect** keyword, linking its call to a function.

So say the part is named **part**, and your function is named **onPartTouched**:

```
part.Touched:connect(onPartTouched)
```

So now whenever our part gets touched, it calls the function **onPartTouched(whatTouchedIt)** where whatTouchedIt would be the object that actually touched the part:

```
function onPartTouched(whatTouchedIt) 
    print(whatTouchedIt)
end
```

would print what touched your object.

Now here you would like to check out if the actual thing that touched your trigger is a player, and do your function of changing the text.

Comment: Thanks! Now I can continue on the development on my game!

Comment: Oh also another question... Sorry to bother you, but dose this script go in the text? Or dose one go into one and one has to go into another?

Answer (score -1):

You can also use:

```
game:GetService("Workspace").Part.Touched:Connect(function()
  script.Parent.Text = "DesiredText"
end)
```

This is better if you made the function only for the event